# Read XML File with Connection String Details in

Tags: c#, sql, xml, string, connection

I have created an XML File in My Project using a form which contains the connection string details that I need to run my program. The XML is formatted like this:

```
<xml encoding="UTF8">
<configuration>
   <appsettings>
     <servername>localhost</servername>
     <serverport>1433</serverport>
     <username>sa</username>
     <password>thepassword</password>
     <database>NorthWind</database>
   </appsettings>
</configuration>
</xml>
```

I need to use the params in the nodes to build my connection string to run a query and dump an Excel file out. can someone show me how to write this into a connection string in my main form.

Comment: Not tried anything just don't know how to build a connection string from my XML params above going a bit crossed eyed I am new to c#

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would suggest using the built in (and preferred way) to do this in .NET. There are two aspects to this:
1. Use application.config files (or web.config for ASP.NET)
2. Use the ConnectionStrings section on these config files.

Config files are the preferred way to store application configuration information and .NET has a lot of built in support for them. Further, there is built-in support for connection strings as well.

So, for example, you application.config file (In Visual Studio, right click on your project's node in solution explorer and choose "Add | New Item...", when that dialog open, choose Application Configuration File)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Orion" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=Orion;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Notice the connectionStrings section. There is one entry (a child node of the ConnectionStrings node). You can give whatever name you want in there and the connectionString attribute of that node will contain the connection string you need. I assume you know what the connection string needs to be.

Now in your application, you'd do something like this:

```
  internal partial class DataModule
  {
    private DbProviderFactory DbProviderFactory { get; set; }
    private DbConnection DbConnection { get; set; }

    public DataModule()
    {
      var connectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Orion"];
      DbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connectionStringSettings.ProviderName);
      DbConnection = DbProviderFactory.CreateConnection();
      DbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionStringSettings.ConnectionString;
    }
  }
```

Notice in this code, I reference the "name" of the connection "Orion" in this case. Be sure to change this to whatever name you gave your connection.

This design also allows you to have multiple "connections" defined in your config file and in your application you could choose to use any one (or more) of these. So for example:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Orion" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=Orion;Integrated Security=True"/>
    <add name="MyOtherOrion" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="server=myserver\myinstancename;database=Orion;uid=myusername;password=mypassword"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then in your application you could just switch to using the "MyOtherOrion" connection.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is using the App.Config like so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=VS.100).aspx

If that's not an option you can use some Linq To Xml if you want (null checks, etc, excluded):
Oh and replace "MyConnectionStringFormatString" with a proper connection string format :).

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

String conStr = 
    doc.Root
    .Elements("configuration")
    .Elements("appsettings")
    .Select(
        s => 
            String.Format("MyConnectionStringFormatString {0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}",
            s.Elements("servername").Single().Value,
            s.Elements("serverport").Single().Value,
            s.Elements("username").Single().Value,
            s.Elements("password").Single().Value,
            s.Elements("database").Single().Value));
```

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for that so if i read that right, I would need to replace the MyConnectionStringFormatString with some thing like 
"Data Source=servername,serverport;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=dataBase;User ID=username;Password=password;"

Comment: Yes, but use {0} for the 1st returned (servername), {1} for the 2nd (serverport), etc. etc.